# Modify dynamically created jQuery checkbox button's css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm creating a series of jQuery checkboxes in a loop like so:

```
var checkbox = $('<input>').attr({type: 'checkbox', id: checkbox_id);
panel.append(checkbox);
panel.append($('<label>').attr({for: checkbox_id}).html(checkbox_name);
checkbox.button();
```

I have a css class called `my-style` that defines things like `border-radius`, `padding`, and `line-height`. I want `my-style` to override the attributes defined by jQuery's theme for only the checkboxes I've created.

I tried `checkbox.addClass("my-style");` and `panel.find(".ui-button-text").addClass("my-style")`, but neither works correctly. Some css attributes do overwrite jQuery's default values, like `border-radius`, and others don't ever seem to be able to be overwritten like `line-height` and `padding`. I even tried to enforce css attributes directly by `panel.find(".ui-button-text").css("line-height", 1.0);`, but that doesn't work at all.

I understand that I could just modify the jQuery theme directly by changing the css code in there, but doing so would affect all buttons made, which is not what I'd like to do.

UPDATE:

One way I've managed to address this issue is by specifying the `style` tag directly. So the code above becomes:

```
var checkbox = $('<input>').attr({type: 'checkbox',
                                  id: checkbox_id});
panel.append(checkbox);
var label = $('<label>').attr({for: checkbox_id,
                               style: "font-size: 0.6em; border-radius: 0px; margin-right: 0.3em;"}).text(checkbox_name);
panel.append(label);
checkbox.button();
label.children().attr("style", "padding: 0.2em 0.4em;");
```

While this solution works, it's unsavory, as I'm mixing JavaScript and CSS code together.

By writing in the `style` attribute, I can override jQuery UI's CSS. One thing that's been discussed here is using more specific CSS selectors that will be given more weight than jQuery UI's CSS classes. A more specific selector would be something that has the checkbox's ID. The problem with this approach is that checkboxes are dynamically generated, and thus so are checkbox IDs. It's therefore not feasible to have more specific CSS selectors from what I understand.

Comment: Have you tried using the `!important` declaration on the css attributes you want to override?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that the class isn't getting applied to the element, or that the class isn't doing what you want it to do?

If the latter, can you paste the css code for your class?

Comment: .cy_tag_button
    {
        font-size: 0.6em;
        padding: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 0px;
        line-height: 1;
    }

Comment: Use Web Inspector or Firebug and see what classes are overriding the styles you defined in .cy_tag_button. It seems like your using jQuery UI and so will likely have more classes defined on your elements that may have a more specific selector for the properties you define in .cy_tag_button.

Comment: The problem with specifying a more specific selector is that each check box has to have its own ID in order to use the `label` tag. How would I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your CSS selector is not specific enough, you have two options here

1. Be nasty and declare your CSS properties with !important to override anything else selected
2. Write a more specific CSS selector

The latter is the better option, as you will have more control over your styling at a later stage. In case you don't know much about CSS selectors take a read of this (http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) which should help understand writing more specific selectors and the value of each selector type.